# Converting Jquery to Javascript(React)

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Hi I hope your having a great day,
I just got into **React** and I was trying to convert my old codes to **React** but the things is my old codes were **Jquery** and I'm having a hard time on converting it to **Vanilla Javascript**.

Here's my old code:

```
function progress() {
    var windowScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docHeight = $(document).height();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var progress = (windowScrollTop / (docHeight - windowHeight)) * 100;

    var bgColor = progress > 99 ? "#fff" : "#fff";
    var textColor = progress > 99 ? "#fff" : "#333";

    $("h1").text(Math.round(progress) + "%").css({ color: textColor });

    $(".fill").height(progress + "%").css({ backgroundColor: bgColor });
}

progress();
```

What I've done so far:

```
let progress = () => {
    let windowScrollTop = window.onscroll;
    let docHeight = document.offsetHeight;
    let windowHeight = window.offsetHeight;
    let progress = (windowScrollTop / (docHeight - windowHeight)) * 100;

    let bgColor = progress > 99 ? "#fff" : "#fff";
    let txtColor = progress > 99 ? "#fff" : "#333";      

    document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = Math.round(progress) + "%";     
    document.querySelector("h1").style.color = bgColor;
            
    document.querySelector(".fill").innerHTML = Math.round(progress) + "%";    
    document.querySelector(".fill").style.color = txtColor;         
}

progress();
```

Lastly the **Math.round()** display **NaN**
[image: Screenshot from 2021-11-04 19-06-35]

I'm really sorry for all the trouble I hope you could help me with my problem. Thank you

Comment: [You should probably start at the beginning](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html). React has a very specific process for updating the DOM, and you shouldn't be using native DOM methods like `querySelector` with it.

Comment: ill try using useRef right now

Comment: still the same good sir

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your request is quite broad and seems to contain multiple questions. You need to ask something more specific, and your title should reflect that single clear question.

Comment: Andy gives good advice up there.  You're not writing react code, you're still writing jQuery-like DOM manipulation and wrapping it in react, which will give you the worst of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

Upon searching and playing around in the code I finally got an answer

```
let windowScrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop
let docHeight = document.documentElement.offsetHeight   
let windowHeight = window.innerHeight
```

Comment: Those things are well-covered on SO. Please give the search box a go.