# How can I convert this jquery methods - .text(), .height() and .css() to vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, ecmascript-6, jquery-selectors

Hi I hope your having a great day,

Today I decided to try it out to convert from jquery to vanilla javascript on my free time but I've been working this code for hours and I'm really having a hard time on converting this code from Jquery to vanilla javascript.

Code I'd like to change

```
$("h1").text(Math.round(progress) + "%").css({ color: textColor });    
$(".fill").height(progress + "%").css({ backgroundColor: bgColor });
```

Full code:

```
function progress() {
    var windowScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docHeight = $(document).height();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var progress = (windowScrollTop / (docHeight - windowHeight)) * 100;

    var bgColor = progress > 99 ? "#fff" : "#fff";
    var textColor = progress > 99 ? "#fff" : "#333";

    $("h1").text(Math.round(progress) + "%").css({ color: textColor });

    $(".fill").height(progress + "%").css({ backgroundColor: bgColor });
}

progress();
```

I'm really sorry for all the trouble I hope you could help me with my problem. Thank you.

Comment: I'm a little confused. [Did you decide to not use React anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69838322/converting-jquery-to-javascriptreact)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need

```
document.querySelector("h1").innerText = Math.round(progress) + "%"
document.querySelector("h1").style.color = textColor
document.querySelector(".fill").style.height = progress + "%"
document.querySelector(".fill").style.backgroundColor = bgColor
```

Small code snippet [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5snhdfap/)
However, there are multiple issues with the snippet considering bad practice.

You should append CSS using a class (helps with iOS).
Also, if you want to put this on multiple element with the same class name/tag name, consider using querySelectorAll with a loop inside.

Comment: Don't forget that `document.querySelector` returns only the first match. If need more, consider using `document.querySelectorAll`

Comment: Already mentioned that @ManuelRomeiro

Comment: Thats true. Sorry for not having read with attention that part.

Comment: @sc0rp1on thank you good sir